# installing virtualbox in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, modprobe

I have installed virtual box on my ubuntu 16.04 following instructions described [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/install-latest-virtualbox-5-1-ubuntu-16-04).

Last command, i.e. `sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1`, gave me this:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

I've tried `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` which gave me:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

Then I tried `dmesg` and uploaded its output [here](http://cdn.persiangig.com/download/1sLEX1GZDx/dmesg-out.txt/dl).

Comment: @Pilot6, I didn't get that error at all. How these two are the same?

Comment: The error must be in your `dmesg` that is not displayed by your link. Run `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` and you'll get it.